# Feasibility with WordPress Scaling

Tags: php, wordpress, cluster-computing, gravity-forms-plugin

We have a WordPress site aiming to have very huge amount of visitors, around 1M within few hours!

And we are already setting up WP Cluster instances on GCP to handle server level requirements with central Database instance. At the same time, we are in need of Gravity Forms plugin to collect data.

Can Gravity Form handle and work flawlessly without any database/table level conflicts like locking, key constraints etc?

Looking forward with your inputs.

Thank you.